# sql query to apply less than / greater than condition on string

Tags: sql

I need to make a sql query, but so far didn't manage...
I need to obtain the results between the reference '400a' and '850a' by model... how can I accomplish that? you can see my picture to understand better..

Can I anyone help me please?

my current sql server query is:

SELECT

Model, IndexOp, Reference, value FROM table

where

IndexOp >= (SELECT IndexOp FROM table where Model = '405a' and Reference = '850a') and

IndexOp <= (SELECT IndexOp FROM table where Model = '405a' and Reference = '850a')

but it doesn't work: Error: Subquery returns multiple rows

[image: my problem - in picture below]

Comment: You have to tell us (and use the appropriate tag of) the sql language you are using.

Comment: No, I cannot use the picture to understand better.  You need to put some effort into explaining what you want to do.

Comment: `...where reference between '400a' and '850'`, will work for _nnnc_ format values.

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply looking for a `where` clause?

```
select t.*
from t
where reference >= '405a' and reference <= '850a';
```

This is not a complex query.

Comment: obviously your query does not work for my problem !!

Comment: @cafc . . . How is that "obvious"?  It appears to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I said obviously because you are comparing strings with > and obviously it doesn't work...

Comment: sorry but is a lot more compex that simple where clause like where reference >= '405a' and reference <= '850a';